# Indexing and searching tree structures with elasticsearch

Tags: elasticsearch

I want to index a catalog structure with folders and objects. Each
folder can contain subfolder and objects.

Mapping:

```
{
    "mappings" : {
        "folder" : {    
            "_parent" : {
                "type" : "folder"
            },
            "properties" : {
                "name" : {
                    "type" : "string"
                }
            }
        },
        "object" : {    
            "_parent" : {
                "type" : "folder"
            },
            "properties" : {
                "name" : {
                    "type" : "string"
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

The depth of the tree structure is unknown.

The search should match all objects which match a specified query and
all items whereby at least one folder in the path match a specified
query. This last part I don't know how to do without nesting the
`has_parent` query many times (which would put a limit on the tree depth).

I think a `match_all` and filter based solution wouldn't work either.

Is there any workable solution for this problem?
(With one query - maybe with a different mapping?)

PS: Duplicating the information of the folders on the item (or vice
versa) is not an option since it's to much information.

Comment: I'm pretty sure you can't. Perhaps you could tell us more about your usecases a bit, so it would be easier to come up with alternative mappings? For instance, In the end you only want to return `objects` not `folders` correct? Moreover will each `folder` have the same type of properties? Are these properties known at design time? Why would you dismiss the logical option as described in your PS beforehand? Could you give us some numbers?

Comment: Yes, at the moment I just want to find `objects`. The biggest catalog right now has about 10000 `elements` (`folders` + `objects`) and a depth of 10 levels. All properties are known at design time and some are required and some are optional. If I indeed would duplicate all `folder` information, the relevance of a special keyword (which belongs to the `folder`) would decrease!?