# Traverse tree in ElasticSearch

Tags: elasticsearch

In our elasticSearch we have folder objects that have a tree structure.  I would like to do a search that basically does a tree traversal up and lists all of the documents in that traversal.  Is this possible with the newer versions of elasticSearch?

I was looking at [Indexing and searching tree structures with elasticsearch](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16688578/indexing-and-searching-tree-structures-with-elasticsearch) in which the answer seemed to be "it's not possible" but it is a few years old.  I've found various examples on the internet of doing a one level nested search, but nothing about a complete traversal.

My intended use case is to say "Give me an ordered list of all of the parents of this folder".  It is an upward traversal to the root.

Comment: Could you elaborate why do you need to travel the tree? What is your search criteria and what is the intended result? Are you for example trying to find all JPG files which are within a folder (or sub-folder) named like "Travel*"?

Answer (score 0):

It doesn't look like this is possible.  In elastic search you can aggregate children but not parents.

https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/guide/2.x/children-agg.html

"Parent-child supports a children aggregation as a direct analog to the nested aggregation discussed in Nested Aggregations. A parent aggregation (the equivalent of reverse_nested) is not supported."